# Attribute value must be a constant in SwaggerConfig

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, swagger-2.0

I have swagger configured for a class and the error for creating base path using constants,

```
public static final String paymentControllerBasePath = "cx/payment/v1"
public static final String payoutControllerBasePath = "cx/payment/v1"
```

If I try to import them into a class, like,
`@Api(tags = { paymentControllerBasePath }, value = "payment functionality", produces = "application/json")`

The tags value in the above line shows an error in IntelliJ saying

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

Well, it is a constant. Can anyone help me mitigate this error?

Answer (score 2):

Please use string literals. Annotations don’t accept variables or constant variables.
Compile time constants are primitive data types only. And annotations don’t accept runtime variables or constants.